# Business rule in db or the previous layer

Tags: database, oracle

In a system, where should the business logic be implemented?? Is it using PL/SQL blocks in the database or in its previous layer say java / .net?

Comment: This is an old chestnut both on SO and on other sites.  It is also a matter of taste.  Because you've tagged this [oracle] and [database] your question will primarily attract Oracle database programmers who will tend to favour "BL in PL/SQL".  However there are many application developers who think the exact opposite.  Alas the split is virtually religious in its intensity and just as unresolvable.  That's why the question is Not Constructive.  So, voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not wanting to be too unhelpful, but the business logic should be implemented in the business logic layer.

If you're actually asking where the business logic layer should be, then it really depends how you want to architect your system.

It sounds like (and I'll assume) that you are referring to the classic 3-tier architecture:

**UI <--> Biz Logic <--> Database**

This tells us that we should separate out UI code from business logic from database logic. Given your scenario this would imply that you should omit business logic from any blocks of PL/SQL code.

Comment: I for one, put the business logic also in the constraints. Is it mixing with the database logic?